# Powerapps If function help (make button disappear)

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am a newbie to powerapps and trying to get to grips with If functions.

There are two buttons 'add' and 'subtract' which displays a variable in a text box.

I would like to make the subtract button disappear when the value is zero in the text box.

Any help is appreciated.

The subtract button's property is set to 'visible'  and  'fx = true'

I guess I need to set the subtract button property to 'false' when the text value is zero?

Comment: OK I've made some progress by using If(My_Variable,false)=false, this makes the subtract button disappear when I get to zero from whole numbers. Does this function look OK and can you explain what is happening please?

Answer (score 0):

Power Apps uses a very *declarative* language (Power Fx). In this language, if you want the 'Subtract' button to be visible if the value of your variable is greater than 0, then you would use an expression like `var > 0` in the Visible property of the button. As the value of the variable is updated, the data flow inside your app will update the Visible property of the button. See the screen capture below for an example:

[image: Visible property and variables]

Comment: Thats great carlos thank you for the explanation, I will give that a try. Are you able to explain why If(My_Variable,false)=false achieves the same result please?

Comment: The If function will return the second argument if the first one is true (if it doesn't have a third argument and the value is false, as it is your case, it will return a blank value). A Boolean variable can have three possible values: Blank (before it is initialized), false or true. If My_Variable is true, then your If expression will return `false`, which is equal to false (so your expression will return true). In any other case, your If expression will return a blank value, which is not equal to false, so your expression will return false.

Comment: Thanks carlos that is very much appreciated, I will need to read a few times I think to try and understand. Thank you

Comment: Trying to put in a table may help visualize it better, but I don't know how to write tables in comments :-|. You can try having a table with three columns: `My_Variable`, `If(My_Variable, false)`, `If(My_Variable, false) = false`, and three rows, one for each possible value of My_Variable (blank, or uninitialized), false and true. The first row values would be blank, blank, false; the second row would be false, blank, false; the third row would be true, false, true. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thats great I will write out the table to help. Just playing with the values and see that I could also have wrote If(My_Variable,true)=true to achieve the same result. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show/hide button based on value in the text box, you can set `Visible` property of button control to:

```
Value(TextInput1.Text) > 0
```

**OR**:

```
If(Value(TextInput1.Text) > 0, true, false)
```

Where `TextInput1` is the name of your text box control in Power Apps.